# how can I tell if pthread_self is the main (first) thread in the process?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

background: I'm working on a logging library that is used by many programs.
I'm assigning a human-readable name for each thread, the main thread should get "main", but I'd like to be able to detect that state from within the library without requiring code at the beginning of each main() function.

Also note: The library code will not always be entered first from the main thread.

Comment: How do you obtain the other human-readable names?

Comment: More specifically, what is the pattern to which `main` fails to conform?

Comment: The majority of threads in the system are started in only a handful of ways.  There is common code there that can rely on a virtual std::string name() function.  The main thread is different though.

Comment: If you can register a name for every other thread as it's started, then perhaps you can assume a thread is `main` if no name has been registered?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is kinda doable, depending on the platform you're on, but absolutely not in any portable and generic way...

Mac OS X seems to be the only one with a direct and documented approach, according to their [pthread.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/pthreads/pthread.h) file:

```
/* returns non-zero if the current thread is the main thread */
int pthread_main_np(void);
```

I also found that FreeBSD has a pthread_np.h header that defines pthread_main_np(), so this should work on FreeBSD too (8.1 at least), and OpenBSD (4.8 at least) has pthread_main_np() defined in pthread.h too. Note that _np explicitly stands for non-portable!

Otherwise, the only more "general" approach that comes to mind is comparing the PID of the process to the TID of the current thread, if they match, that thread is main.
This does not necessarily work on all platforms, it depends on if you can actually get a TID at all (you can't in OpenBSD for example), and if you do, if it has any relation to the PID at all or if the threading subsystem has its own accounting that doesn't necessarily relate.

I also found that some platforms give back constant values as TID for the main thread, so you can just check for those.

A brief summary of platforms I've checked:

- Linux: **possible here**, syscall(SYS_gettid) == getpid() is what you want
- FreeBSD: not possible here, thr_self() seems random and without relation to getpid()
- OpenBSD: not possible here, there is no way to get a TID
- NetBSD: **possible here**, _lwp_self() always returns 1 for the main thread
- Solaris: **possible here**, pthread_self() always returns 1 for the main thread

So basically you should be able to do it directly on Mac OS X, FreeBSD and OpenBSD.

You can use the TID == PID approach on Linux.

You can use the TID == 1 approach on NetBSD and Solaris.

I hope this helps, have a good day!

Comment: MacOSX having strong roots in *BSD sort of explains where its use of `pthread_main_np()` comes from. It's a fully documented interface (got a manpage) on all the *BSDs as well. Solaris has the equivalent as `thr_main()` and you could simply `#define pthread_main_np thr_main` there. Better use that than the `TID == 1` trick.

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but if you also plan on writing for iOS, the pthread_main_np() function is also supported.

Answer (score 11):

Call pthread_self() from main() and record the result.  Compare future calls to pthread_self() to your stored value to know if you're on the main thread.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that this library is used by MANY programs.  Adding new code to each and every one is undesirable.

Comment: You can use `__attribute__((constructor))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize some kind of shared name resource that allows threads that spawn to register a name (perhaps a map of thread id to name).  Your logging system can then place a call into a method that gets the name via the thread ID in a thread-safe manner.

When the thread dies, have it remove it's name from the mapping to avoid leaking memory.

This method should allow all threads to be named, not just main.

Comment: I've already got all this.  This does not help with automatic determination of which thread is main.