# Difference between __NR_gettid and SYS_gettid

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I was just looking at the way to get unique thread ID's in Linux. The way I found was to do as syscall with either of the two parameters as arguments: `__NR_gettid` OR `SYS_gettid`.

Can anybody explain how they both differ with respect to each other?

Comment: Note, for _usages_ of these system calls, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63827823/4561887): `#define gettid() ((pid_t)syscall(SYS_gettid))`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211287/4561887):`pid_t x = syscall(__NR_gettid);`, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311517/4561887): `pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);`.

Answer (score 18):

Nothing

in `<bits/syscall.h>` there is this:

```
#define SYS_gettid __NR_gettid
```

Comment: Correct for this one. However, `SYS_xzy` are the preferred symbol to access a syscall.

Comment: On modern systems, `<bits/syscall.h>` seems to simply include either `<bits/syscall-32.h>` or `<bits/syscall-64.h>` (depending on whether your system is 32 or 64 bits), which then has that `#define SYS_gettid __NR_gettid` line.