# How to get PID of QThread in Linux?

Tags: linux, qt, pid, qthread

I need to get PID of specific QThread in linux. `getpid` returns pid of parent process. `getCurrentThreadId` returns Qt inner code. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21280941/2656799

It is in use of `syscall(SYS_gettid)`